# Modify one form instance in a Django formset?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django formset in which I render four instances of a form. Each form in the formset has two fields, but I want the last (4th) instance to only show/input one field. How can I do this, or is there a better way? I tried limiting the formset to three fields and making the fourth instance its own form, but I need to validate that `field1` against the `field1` fields in the formset. I couldn't see how to validate a form against a simultaneously submitted formset.

views.py:

```
FormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, formset=BaseMyFormSet, extra=4)
```

.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
    <div>
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

The formset has two fields in forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # field1
    # field2
```

How do I make it so the first three forms in the formset have two fields, but the last only contains `field1`?

Comment: You might try to override your formset's [`forms` property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/forms/formsets.py#L127) and instantiate the list of forms explicitly according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly removing the field for the last form in your views.py:

```
def view_func(request):
    FormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, formset=BaseMyFormSet, extra=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # assuming this is a required field for the other forms
        formset.forms[-1].fields['field2'].required = False

        if formset.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        formset = FormSet()

    del formset.forms[-1].fields['field2']
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Any further adjustments depend on your form and validation logic. `BaseMyFormSet.clean()` is the appropriate place for [formset-wide validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) and it sounds like you already have code there to compare `field1` across forms.

(From a purist sense, it might be better to have the FormSet class handle this entirely, but this is easier. FormSet code is decently complex. It'd make sense to override [BaseFormSet.forms()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.2/django/forms/formsets.py#L127-L134) but with that `@cached_property` bit, you're involved with implementation details best left to Django.)